# QtCreator scroll jumps after mouse click

Tags: qt, logitech, qt-creator, mouse-scroll

I've already asked on the Qt forum, but apparently Ubuntu users aren't there.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Place the cursor somewhere.
2. Scroll down with a mouse wheel so the cursor is not in sight any more.
3. Select some text.
4. Start scrolling up or down with the mouse wheel.

And instead of scrolling, it jumps up for a big amount.

3.5.1 or 3.1.1

Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59764

The problem is somehow related to the Logitech G300 mouse.

Same: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=97510

G300 is two devices: mouse and keyboard. Looks like the keyboard events confuse the input system.

Workaround that fixes scrolling, but disables most of additional buttons (depending on how they are programmed):

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Ignore keyboard mouse device"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchProduct "Logitech Gaming Mouse G300"
    Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection
```